# Tab Navigation and Action Bar

Tags: android, navigation

This is a program for making an android application wherein there are a few action buttons and three navigation tabs. The application unfortunately closes everytime.

Here's my LogCat

```
09-18 00:15:40.157: D/AndroidRuntime(634): Shutting down VM
09-18 00:15:40.157: W/dalvikvm(634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:389)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-18 00:15:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 00:15:44.757: I/Process(634): Sending signal. PID: 634 SIG: 9
```

Here's the MainActivity:

```
package info.androidhive.actionbar;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

// @SuppressLint("NewApi")

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

 private ViewPager viewPager;
 private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
// action bar
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Refresh menu item
private MenuItem refreshMenuItem;

  // Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Home", "Genre", "Mood" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Hide the action bar title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   // actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }


    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    // Associate search-able configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * On selecting action bar icons
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;
    case R.id.action_favourite:
        // load favourite
        Fav();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        // refresh
        refreshMenuItem = item;
        // load the data from server
        new SyncData().execute();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_help:
        // help action
        return true;
    case R.id.action_check_updates:
        // check for updates action
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Launching new activity
 * */
private void Fav() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Favourite.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * Async task to load the data from server
 * **/
private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // set the progress bar view
        refreshMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_progressbar);

//          refreshMenuItem.expandActionView();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // not making real request in this demo
        // for now we use a timer to wait for sometime
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
//          refreshMenuItem.collapseActionView();
        // remove the progress bar view
        refreshMenuItem.setActionView(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
            // show respected fragment view
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


  }

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  };

}
```

There's a package with the name info.androidhive.tabsswipe and main package with name info.androidhive.actionbar

Comment: Are you learning how to make tabed activity or its just a functionality you want in your application ?

Comment: It is a functionality needed in the application

Comment: Then i would suggest in eclips juno there is an option to create tabbed activity with swipe and tabs. While creating a new application chose accordingly and build your application over it.

Answer (score 0):

did you add something like this in your activity resource xml file?

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Yes I did.
Its there in the main activity xml file for tab navigation